# How to combine string and variable for html property in React with Typescript

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I have React + Typescript app. I would like to set href attribute for  HTML element which should be a combination of string and variable value.
I suppose it should be something like this:
...<a href={`/user${userid}`}>...

But it does not work.
The question is how to set href property correctly in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
<a href={`/user${userid}`}>href</a>
```